# Sharing Async Actions in Redux

Tags: asynchronous, redux

I am new to Redux. I am wondering about a best approach to using an isFetching flag for multiple different reducers.

I am following something similar to this example:
http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Except I have 2 separate API calls. When I send out API call I dispatch an action that sets isFetching : true.

`return Object.assign({}, state, {isFetching: true});`

When I get response I set isFetching:false.

`return Object.assign({}, state, {data: myData}, {isFetching: false});`

The issue is isFetching is global in my state, so if I am correct they can overwrite eachother. What is the best way to use a generic 'AJAX_FETCHING' or 'AJAX_DONE' action that multiple reducers can use independent of each other?

Comment: Would you be opposed to having multiple `isFetching` in your application? You could then infer the state by looking at all of them. As a bonus, you would be able to see exactly what is fetching at any time.

Comment: If you don't care about the actual request being pending, keep a counter (`fetchingCount`) which will be increased when request starts and decreased when it ends. If `fetchingCount` is 0, you're ready.

Comment: @MarioTacke I am not opposed to that, I am just trying to figure out the best way to keep my async flags manageable. And without having to create a new Action for isFetching for each reducer.